# Go to URL after selecting an option in optgroup

Tags: javascript, jquery, optgroup

I want to learn how to use JavaScript (or the jQuery library) in order to go to a url indicated as a value of the option tag inside an optgroup tag.

With a simple, one-level select tag containing option tags, the solution can be similar to that described [in this post](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/navmenu.html):

```
<FORM NAME="nav"><DIV>
<SELECT NAME="SelectURL" onChange=
"document.location.href=
document.nav.SelectURL.options[document.nav.SelectURL.selectedIndex].value">
<OPTION VALUE="http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/jsnav.html"
SELECTED>Please select an item:
<OPTION VALUE="http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/">
Main page on HTML forms
<OPTION VALUE="http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/choices.html">
Choices in HTML forms
<OPTION VALUE="http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/tables.html">
Tables and forms
<OPTION VALUE="http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html">
Form submission methods (GET and POST)
</SELECT><DIV>
</FORM>
```

I tried to use it with a two-level select tag with option tags inside optgroup tags – and it's not working for me. I'd appreciate help with adapting this code.

Comment: You've gotta close the option tags.

Comment: Good point, @Seza. Credit for the code belongs to the author of the quoted tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to do it when the user selects an option:

```
$('select[name="SelectURL"]').change(function() {
    window.location.replace($(this).val());
});
```

Or this when the user clicks a submit button:

```
$('form[name="nag"]').on('submit' function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.replace($('select[name="SelectURL"]').val());
});
```

You should also clean up you HTML like this:

```
<FORM NAME="nav">
    <DIV>
        <SELECT NAME="SelectURL">
            <OPTION VALUE="http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/jsnav.html" SELECTED>Please select an item:</OPTION>
            <OPTION VALUE="http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/"> Main page on HTML forms</OPTION>
            <OPTION VALUE="http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/choices.html"> Choices in HTML forms</OPTION>
            <OPTION VALUE="http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/tables.html"> Tables and forms</OPTION>
            <OPTION VALUE="http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html"> Form submission methods (GET and POST)</OPTION>
        </SELECT>
    <DIV>
</FORM>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it open in a new window, @Joe?

Comment: You can use: `window.open($(this).val(),'_blank');` (top code block) or `window.open($('select[name="SelectURL"]').val(),'_blank');` (second code block) instead of `window.location.replace`.

Comment: Actually, @Joe – it doesn't seem to work in Safari, Chrome and IE, for some reason. Works only in FF – any suggestions on how this can be fixed?

Comment: Quite a few browsers/adblockers stop it to prevent users getting spammed with pop-ups. The best method is probably `window.location.replace()` even though it won't allow you to open it in a new window.

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work in IE even with location.replace. May I ask you to take a look at the actual page, @Joe?

Comment: Hm... interesting. This works in all browsers, thank you! But could you tell me, why is this method less user-friendly, @Joe?

Comment: Its auto loads the page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all get rid of the inline onChange event handler:

```
<FORM NAME="nav"><DIV>
<SELECT NAME="SelectURL">
<OPTION VALUE="http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/jsnav.html"
SELECTED>Please select an item:
<OPTION VALUE="http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/">
Main page on HTML forms
<OPTION VALUE="http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/choices.html">
Choices in HTML forms
<OPTION VALUE="http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/tables.html">
Tables and forms
<OPTION VALUE="http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html">
Form submission methods (GET and POST)
</SELECT><DIV>
</FORM>
```

Then just add an event listener:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
  $('select[name=SelectURL]').change(function(v)
  {
    window.location.replace( $(this).val() );
  });
});
```